# why call schedule explicitly in sys_sched_yield in linux 2.4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I'm taking an OS class and we're looking at the scheduler, my question is about when to explicitly call schedule().

In linux 2.4, scheduler is called after 'need_resched' flag is set, why do we explicitly call schedule() in sys_sched_yield(), and what would happen if we just set the flag instead?

Comment: if you just set the flag then *current* process will not be preempted until just before returning to userspace. by calling schedule() you are preempting *current* out.